# Cordova Inapp browser throws error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, inappbrowser

I get the followin error when I ue Cordova Inappbrowser (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/)

```css
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
```

```css
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open(urlToGo, '_self', options)
              .then(function(event) {
                // success
                console.log("Success...");
              })
              .catch(function(event) {
                // error
                console.log("Error...");
              });


              $cordovaInAppBrowser.close();
```

Comment: where you are testing it ? in web browser or device ? it will not work in web browser.

Comment: testing in emulator an d device

Comment: $cordovaInAppBrowser - Is this should be something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and wrap your code in a device ready first;

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

  $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(urlToGo, '_self', options)
    .then(function(event) {
      // success
      console.log("Success...");
     })
     .catch(function(event) {
       // error
       console.log("Error...");
     });


     $cordovaInAppBrowser.close();

}, false);
```

If that doesnt work try the official [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser).
I sometimes find that ng plugins dont always play nice.

Their example to trigger the browser.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
  window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
}
```

Comment: its throwing - Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. I used second option

Comment: It did not work. Its still throwing - TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined and error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: Is it possible to come back to my app? Because once success, I am giving - $location.path('/detail');, but its not coming to my app :(, as its new widnow

Comment: Do this in your option tag for Back button var options = {
                toolbar: 'yes',
                closebuttoncaption:'Done',
                toolbarposition:'top'
            };